# how to use mobile jquery to develope mobile application

Tags: jsp, jquery-mobile, servlets

I want to use mobile jquery for vehicle tracking on google map. I wonder how to use and which jquery will need to use in that application. Also, which version will be best to user mobile jquery.
Currently i am using this for mobile jquery but it dont seems to work perfectly or may be i dont know how to use basically with google map.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

please guide me to use mobile jquery...?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is not a guiding site: To begin, read here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/